# Postgresql 9.2 date ranges overlap with conditions

Tags: postgresql, range, date-range, postgresql-9.2

As I see in documentation there is a possibility to create gist index which will reject overlapping ranges

```
CREATE TABLE room_reservation (
    room text,
    during daterange,
    EXCLUDE USING gist (room WITH =, during WITH &&)
);
```

It works perfect, but how to adjust it to not count infinite range - '(,)' (e.g. range from -inf to inf) as overlapped to anything except self. For example i want to allow adding only one row with infinite bounds and rest date ranges should just use && operator to check.

valid data:

```
| room | during                   |
| r1   | (,)                      |
| r2   | (10.09.2012, 10.09.2013) |
| r2   | (11.09.2013, 11.11.2013  |
```

and inserting row with during = (01.01.2013, 01.01.2015) will throw and error.

Comment: You should be able to ignore the infinite ranges by using a partial index by adding the correct "WHERE (predicate)" to your exclude constraint (see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand jug's comment

```
 EXCLUDE USING gist (room WITH =, during WITH &&) WHERE( !isempty(during))
```